# Reconstruction of square from normvectors to the corners (perspective view of square).

Tags: matrices, geometry, 3d, projection

I have the following case (three-dimensional space): A square is projected with a perspective projection into a point, and the norm vectors directed to the four corners of this square are known.

The four norm vectors are $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}, \vec{D}$. They point to (but do not reach!) the fours corners of the square with sides of length $l$ (in rotational order, so $\vec{A}$ points to the opposite corner of the one $\vec{C}$ points to). My question is: how to find the coordinates of the corners of the square, given these normal vectors and $l$? There is a certain error in $\vec{A}, \vec{B}, \vec{C}, \vec{D}$ and i'm not sure if this means there might not be a solution. If there is no exact solution, an approximation or something similar to least-squares is welcome.

Thanks for any help!

PS. I have tried to use wolfram cloud but it does not find an answer using the following formulation (due to a timeout):

```
Solve[{ 
    Norm[a*{a1,a2,a3} - b*{b1,b2,b3}] == l,
    Norm[b*{b1,b2,b3} - c*{c1,c2,c3}] == l,
    Norm[c*{c1,c2,c3} - d*{d1,d2,d3}] == l,
    Norm[d*{d1,d2,d3} - a*{a1,a2,a3}] == l,
    Norm[a*{a1,a2,a3} - c*{c1,c2,c3}] == l*sqrt[2],
    Norm[b*{b1,b2,b3} - d*{d1,d2,d3}] == l*sqrt[2]
    }, {a,b,c,d}]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normalized" ? Usually this term means "norm = 1"... Maybe here, you mean "having the same norm" ? Could you confirm ? Besides something puzzles me in your equations, they seem to have (slightly ?) different norms ; what $a,b,c,d$ stand for ?

Comment: Variables $a,b,c,d$ stand for the length of the vectors from the origin to the corners of the square. Knowing these gives the position of the square.
And yes, I mean "norm=1".

Comment: One thing again : you should mention this is a 3D issue.

Comment: Do you know SVD (Singular Value Decomposition) ?

Comment: I don't know SVD.

Comment: I am going to write in the coming hours a solution using SVD (which is plainly an extension of eigenvalues/eigenvectors decomposition), but you can make use of it trough "blackboxes" ; for example, I use Matlab which has a function "svd" at the same level as function "eig".

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated! Could you note on how errors in the norm vectors would effect the result using SVD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a method to solve my own problem.
We use value $a,b,c$ as the distances of the corners pointed to by respectively $\vec{A},\vec{B},\vec{C}$.

1. Use a searching method for "optimal" $a$.
2. For each $a$, set a corner of the square at $a\vec{A}$.
3. Use trigonometry to find the possible locations of the opposite corner of the square at $c\vec{C}$. There can 0, 1, or 2 possible values for $c$.
4. For each of the values of $c$, find the third corner of the square using $b\vec{B}$. Per value of $c$ there are again 0, 1, or 2 options for $b$.
5. For each version of the triangle $a, b, c$ the fourth corner of the square can now be computed exactly at $\vec{D'}$. The error of this version of the square (choices $a, b, c$) can now be determined by angle between $\vec{D'}$ and $\vec{D}$.
6. Select the version of the square such that you have the lowest error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue that falls into the category of ["Procustes problems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem).

In this Wikipedia article you will see that the key fact is to work on the $3 \times 3$ matrix : $C=BA^T$ where

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}a_1&b_1&c_1&d_1\\a_2&b_2&c_2&d_2\\a_3&b_3&c_3&d_3 \end{pmatrix}$$

(your notations : the coordinates of the 4 points, each one in a column) and

$$B=\ell/2\left(\begin{array}{rrrr}1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\\a&a&a&a \end{array}\right)$$

which is the "perfect (horizontal) square" (please note the $\ell/2$ factor and the fact that $a \ell/2$ is the unknow distance of origin to the horizontal plane of reference. We will have to take several values of $a$ in a reasonable range).

Then ask for the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) of $C$ (using an adequate software) :

$$C=U\Sigma V^T$$

where $U,V$ are orthogonal $3 \times 3$ matrices (and $\Sigma$ the diagonal matrix of the so-called "singular values").

Then the rotation which brings the columns of $A$ "at best" onto the columns of $B$ is

$$R=UV^T$$

Moreover the discrepancy (the degree to which the real points are close or not to a perfect square) is measured by the (squared) Frobenius norm of the gap :

$$d=\|B-RA\|^2_F$$

which is nothing else than the sum of the squares of all entries of matrix $B-RA$

(which is naturally $0$ in the case of a "perfect matching").

Remarks :

1) About $a$ : either we take brute force sweemping, or if processing times matter, we can take an initial value of $a$ and then replace $a+\Delta a$ with a small increment $\Delta a$ ; if the discrepancy obtained with $a+\Delta a$ is smaller than with $a$, it will indicate not only that the direction of move is the good one but will even allow a convergence acceleration.

2) It may happen that $R$ is a symmetry matrix instead of a rotation ; this happens only if the vectors in matrix $A$ haven't been placed according to a direct orientation.

3) Matlab program :

> ```
> A=[0.6 0.5 0.4 0.6
>    1.1 0.9 -0.9 -1.1
>    1.1 -1.1 -1 1.1];
> for k=1:20
>    a=k/10;
>    B=[1 1 -1 -1
>       1 -1 -1 1
>       a a  a  a];
>    C=B*A';
>    [U,S,V]=svd(C);
>    R=U*V';
>    s(k)=sum(sum((B-R*A).^2));% square of Frobenius norm 
> end;
> s, % minimum for a=0.5 in this example
> ```

Comment: This looks very promising, I will come back to you after implementing it!

Comment: Why does the side remark refer to a cube? As the shape we are looking for is a square?

Comment: About the cube : reading back your question : indeed, there is no cube mentionned ! Therefore, as we don't know the distance of teh origin to the plane in which are  (approximately) the four points,  the method has to be slightly modified. I am going to change it in the text of my answer.

Comment: See the change in matrix $B$ and the new Remark 1.

Comment: I just added a Matlab program to help you in your programmation. Which scientific  language are you used to ?

Comment: The matlab example is clear, however, the columns in A don't seem to be norm vectors? Is that on purpose?

Comment: No, I confess I had forgotten this constraint... But it should work anyway. I had as well an afterthought : $a$ can be estimated as the length of barycenter $\frac14(\vec{A}+\vec{B}+\vec{C}+\vec{D})$ (= height of pyramid)

Comment: Just to make sure we understand eachother, the vectors in A are not supposed to actually "reach" the corners of the square, they only point in the direction (I have edited the post).

Comment: Therefore, my matrix $A$ hasn't to have unit length columns...

Comment: When i use matlab with your code example i indeed get a different solution when the vectors in A are normalized.